# Homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z_{6}$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z_{6}$

I have proven that the number of Homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_6 \rightarrow \mathbb Z=6$

Is the reverse just simply $6$ also?

in $\mathbb Z_6$ we have $1+1+1+1+1+1=6=0$

let $f(1)=a \in \mathbb Z$

$f(1+1+1+1+1+1)=f(0)=0$

$6f(1)=0$

$6a=0 \in \mathbb Z_6$

So is $a=\mathbb Z$ or is $a=0,1,2,3,4,5$

Any explanation on this would be great.

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z_6 = 6$ instead of $\mathbb Z_6 \to \mathbb Z = 6$? Because there are no nontrivial homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_6 \to \mathbb Z$.

Comment: There are not six homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_6$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. In fact, only the trivial map $\mathbb{Z}_6\to \mathbb{Z}$ is well defined. Because, suppose $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}_6\to\mathbb{Z}$ maps $\bar{1}$ to some $n$. Then $6n=6\cdot \varphi(\bar{1})=\varphi(\bar{6})=\varphi(\bar{0})=0$, hence $n=0$.

Comment: @David Oops. Ignore my previous comment, I misread your question.

Comment: @EBP Thanks. So just the trivial map hence the number of homomorphisms is $1$ correct?

Comment: @David yes! There is only one homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_6\to \mathbb{Z}$. However, there are indeed $6$ homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_6$, mapping the generator $1$ to any element in $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Answer (score 2):

How did you prove that $\left|\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_6,\mathbb{Z})\right| = 6$? We can state that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ $\left|\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z})\right| = 1$ which result to be the trivial homomorphism, since from the [First Homomorphism Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems)

$ \mathbb{Z}_n / \operatorname{Ker}(\varphi) \cong \operatorname{Im}(\varphi) < \mathbb{Z}$, but all the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $d\mathbb{Z}$ which of course are infinite, and since $|\mathbb{Z}_n / \operatorname{Ker}(\varphi)| < +\infty$ we have $d = 0$ hence $\operatorname{Ker}(\varphi) = \mathbb{Z}_n$

Conversely to count $\left|\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}_6)\right|$ we know they are determined once assigned the image of a generator since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic group.

Because we can choose $\phi(1)$ in $|\mathbb{Z_{6}}| = 6$ ways there are 6 such homomorphisms.

Comment: See my edits for proper MathJax usage. In particular: (1) One should write $\mathbb{Z}_n,$ not $\mathbb{Z_n},$ i.e. the subscript doesn't belong within \mathbb{}. (2) Note the use of \operatorname{}. This does not only de-italicize things, but also results in context-dependent spacing. (3) \left| and \right| in this case do not alter the sizes of the delimiaters, but they affect the horizontal spacing.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I saw the edit, thanks a lot, trying to get better